# Zum ersten Mal : time phrase or manner phrase

Tags: word-order, phrase, time

What is the type of this phrase:

> zum ersten Mal

Is it at time phrase or a manner phrase? I just want to know the order of such an expression, because of the rule that time comes first, then manner, then place.

Comment: Can you give more context, so that it becomes clear, why this makes a difference?

Comment: Because of the order of phrases :time phrase then manner phrase then place phrase

Comment: @Kurusakibill074: Please do not post comments when asked for more context. Instead, please edit your question and add the context there. In your question, tell us what you have done so far to find an answer. Give some example sentences where your problem shows up. Please also read other questions and compare the effort that the writers of those questions have put in with the effort you have put in to ask a good question. Please read this: https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're thinking of the time-manner-place rule, and while this is often taught to learners, it's probably not very useful when trying to analyze what you hear from native speakers. This is why native speakers may not see the relevance of the time vs. manner distinction. You might try an example which includes other phrases of time and manner an ask in which order the phrases would appear when translated. The example I came up with was "I saw her clearly today for the first time."

Answer (score 0):

Adverbials can be separated into 4 groups.
The rule "time, manner, place" only exists for the 3rd group of adverbials.
I would categorize "zum ersten Mal" as an adverbial expressing repetition, because it is implied that a second time could happen.

Assuming that this is correct, your adverbial would be between time and manner adverbial.

Situational adverbials:

- rhematic temporal adverbials (time)
- **Adverbials expressing repetition**
- Adverbials expressing a duration
- Adverbials expressing a reason
- modal adverbials that refer to an event
- Adverbials indicating an accompaniment
- Adverbials expressing the subject attitude
- Adverbs denoting a means or tool
- Modal adverbials in the narrow sense
- rhematic local adverbials (place)

> Er ist gestern(time) zum ersten Mal(rep.) für 8 Stunden(duration) zum Einkaufen(reason) mit seiner Mutter(accompaniment) mit dem Bus(means or tool) auf der Autobahn(place) in die Stadt(direction) gefahren.

Comment: You can place "zum ersten Mal" in front of *any* of the adverbials of your example sentence, denoting that it applies to that specific adverbial. Your "ordering rule" doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @tofro What type of adverbial would you categorize it as, then? Repetition is the only one that makes sense to me.

Comment: Classification is all right, no problems with that. But We need to  understand that this adverbial doesn't directly modify the predicate, but rather other adverbials (specifically the ones it's close to in the sentence).. That would classify it as a *modifier* adverbial-

Comment: I might be dumb, but what does "rhematic" mean? I never heard that word and the dictionaries I consulted didn't either.